# Animation Key Frame Summary - Change editor text color

Tags: animation, edit-mode, color

The screen capture shows the area I am trying to change.
Currently the text color is light grey, which I can barely see.

I am using Auto Rig Pro which looks to be changing the background colors, though I do not see where to change the text color. Not sure if that part helps.

[image]

I looked at Preferences > Themes
I was not able to find anything that would change the above IK title color.

[image]

If anyone can point out where it is I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long time since I changed mine but I *think* you'll find that setting in Preferences > Themes > Dope Sheet. Scroll down to 'Theme Space List', click the down arrow, and the setting should be under 'Source List Text'. If not, it's in 'Theme Space' settings above that section. Have a play with the colors (making a note of the current setting) and see what's changing in the interface.

Comment: That was it, thank you!  -- I would have up-voted but my account is new...

Comment: Good! Glad it helped!